# Apex - Getting secret keys out of apxc and apxt files

Tags: apex, encryption

I'm working on Salesforce Apex trigger that needs to encrypt a message and send to an outgoing external rest service.

I have this working great. Here is my Key management class apxc file:

```
public class KeyManage {
    public static String getIv() {
        return 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx removed for privacy ==';
    }
    public static String getKey() {
        return 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx removed for privacy ==';
    }
    public static String getAlgorithm() {
        return 'AES128';
    }
}
```

This doesn't quite seem secure, because I have hard coded tokens in my Apxc file.

How can I get my hard coded key strings out of apxc files? Or is this not even a security problem?

I saw some mention of using "custom settings" but i had no luck trying it.

Is there something that can go:  `GlobalVariables.security.iv` or something like that?

Comment: I am afraid we have no idea what you are asking. Try thinking about how you would need to be asked this question (and update your question). If it was asked as you stated above and you had NO knowledge of the context, could you answer it?

Comment: How is 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' generated? Is it constant or auto-changing?

Comment: @amit constant unless someone wants to refresh the keys.

Comment: @Eric there you go. is that better?

Comment: Who are you protecting your secrets from? Your developers? Your users? Your clients' users? What happens if a compromise does occur? Do you need to use your own IV, or are you willing to accept a Managed IV?

Comment: That's basically my question in a nutshell @sfdcfox. Is it ok to just leave those hard coded values in the KeyManage class I have created? Yes the developers and everyone with access to salesforce is trusted. I just want to make sure it's secure otherwise.

Comment: i added onto my question to include one key text: "Or is that even a problem"

Comment: I use Custom Settings for this.  i store stuff like keys & secrets in a hierarchical custom setting and then when my code needs to access it I create an instance of my custom setting and get the variables. The upside to this method is that whenever the keys need to be changed it can be done easily through the admin UI, but your method requires a redeploy of code upon key change.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of Apex code that can grab the custom setting? Then make it an answer and I'll +1 this? People besides me i'm sure would love to see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options in Apex to protected sensitive information. See [Storing Sensitive Data - Apex and Visualforce Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets#Apex_and_Visualforce_Applications).

If you are creating a managed package then protected custom settings are a great option. You can retrieve and update these values from your Apex code to directly access the unencrypted values. This is particularly useful versus hardcoding the values into Apex if you need to change the values at some future point. If you do create a VF page that allows users to update the stored values be sure to use the `transient` keyword for the backing variables to keep the values out of viewstate.

Basic retrieval of a custom setting:

```
SomeProtectedHierarchyCustomSetting__c existing = SomeProtectedHierarchyCustomSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
// TODO: check for null incase there are no stored values
String key = existing.key__c;
```

Basic insertion of a custom setting:

```
SomeProtectedHierarchyCustomSetting__c newCs = = new SomeProtectedHierarchyCustomSetting__c();
newCs.key__c = 'secret';
insert newCs;
```

When the managed package is installed you will need to consider how to initialise these values.

Comment: It worked. Done and done.

Comment: The important part i had been missing was after you create the custom setting, you need to click "Manage" and create one custom setting record.